# Angular not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

I have an app that works fine in Firefox, IE, Safari and Chrome. But in Chrome it stops working when the contoller below runs. By not working I mean that after $auth.login(user_info) executes the code inside the promise fails. For example if the call returns succesfully the app stops working. Nothing happens when you click on any links. $location.path(lpath) should go to the home page but it doesn't and toastr.success("Login Success"); should display a message but just shows a white popup.

If I run Chrome using Chrome.exe --disable-web-security then everything works. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
angular.module("MyApp")
  .controller("LoginCtrl", function($rootScope, $scope, $location, $auth, toastr) {
    var lpath = "/home";
    $scope.login = function() {
      var user_info = { email:$scope.user.email, password:hex_sha512($scope.user.password)} ;
      $auth.login(user_info)
        .then(function(response) 
        {
          if(response.data.rtn == "true") 
          {
            $location.path(lpath);
            toastr.success("Login Success");
          } 
          else 
          {
            toastr.error(response.data.msg);  
          }
        })
        .catch(function(response) 
        {
          toastr.error("Host Login Error!");
        });
    };

  });


  $auth.login = function(user, opts) {
      opts = opts || {};
      opts.url = config.baseUrl ? utils.joinUrl(config.baseUrl, config.loginUrl) : config.loginUrl;
      opts.data = user || opts.data;
      opts.method = opts.method || 'POST';

      return $http(opts).then(function(response) {
        shared.setToken(response);
        return response;
      });
    };

    Shared.setToken = function(response) {
      var accessToken = response && response.access_token;
      var token;

      if (accessToken) {
        if (angular.isObject(accessToken) && angular.isObject(accessToken.data)) {
          response = accessToken;
        } else if (angular.isString(accessToken)) {
          token = accessToken;
        }
      }

      if (!token && response) {
        var tokenRootData = config.tokenRoot && config.tokenRoot.split('.').reduce(function(o, x) { return o[x]; }, response.data);
        token = tokenRootData ? tokenRootData[config.tokenName] : response.data[config.tokenName];
      }

      if (!token) {
        var tokenPath = config.tokenRoot ? config.tokenRoot + '.' + config.tokenName : config.tokenName;
        throw new Error('Expecting a token named "' + tokenPath + '" but instead got: ' + JSON.stringify(response.data));
      }

      storage.set(tokenName, token);
      storage.set(emailName, response.data.email);
      storage.set(permsName, response.data.permissions);

    };
```

Comment: Can you show the code for `setToken()`?

Comment: Any messages in your console?

Comment: seems like a CORS issue.

Comment: I added the code for setToken(). No messages in console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting as an answer because I don't have the rep.

I would say it is not in this code but in your controller for /home.  Did you try removing code until it works?

Are you sure it did pass and tokens are valid?  Try clearing the cache CTRL-SHIFT-END.  You probably hit some code that wants a valid token and can't continue because you didn't catch failed case.

ANSWER (from Tony): Seems that the periods in the string cause the problem. If I remove the periods it works fine.

Comment: Yes thanks for the reply. It is localStorage.setItem() that fails when I save the following string : "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6IjIiLCJpYXQiOnsiZGF0ZSI6IjIwMTUtMTEtMTAgMDA6Mzg6MjQiLCJ0aW1lem9uZV90eXBlIjozLCJ0aW1lem9uZSI6IlVUQyJ9LCJleHAiOnsiZGF0ZSI6IjIwMTUtMTEtMTAgMDA6Mzg6MjQiLCJ0aW1lem9uZV90eXBlIjozLCJ0aW1lem9uZSI6IlVUQyJ9fQ.3heUGt7JGDbBEk1rQV5UQcrosonBXTi9Ni5dTQJT4t8"

Comment: Seems that the periods in the string cause the problem. If I remove the periods it works fine.

Comment: Cool - please up vote me I need 50 rep so I can add comments.